# Node JS 8.12.0 unable to install on windows 64 bit.

Tags: node.js, installation, windows64

node-v8.12.0-x64.msi Using this file downloaded from the website, I am installing Node js on my windows 64 bit. Home Personal computer. 
I do have Java installed. 
UNable to install node js as there is some missing DLL which I am not understanding.
Kindly please help.

[node js win64 installation error missing dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZq3b.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to similar problems encountered on the web, this error may come from different reasons:

- Windows is not updated.
- Not full access to the folder: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\ or C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp.

Please ensure those two points are ok...

Comment: I am getting update notification of failed to update windows 10. I dont want to upgrade to windows 10.